# Generic types references each other

Tags: c#, generics, generic-constraints

I write simple parser and want to implement next two interfaces:

```
public interface IResult<TValue, TToken> 
    where TToken : ITokenizer<IResult<TValue, TToken>, TValue>
{
    TToken Tokenizer { get; }
    TValue Value { get; }
}

public interface ITokenizer<TResult, TValue> 
    where TResult : IResult<TValue, ITokenizer<TResult, TValue>>
{
    TResult Advance();
}
```

It has next purpose: `ITokenizer` is an immutable class for splitting the string by tokens. We can call `Advance` method and get `Result`: next token and next tokenizer. So, I want store token and tokenizer in `Result` class and want add compile-time constraint for this.

Now I have a compile-time error during construct this two interfaces.

I thought that next classes can implement interfaces with all constraints:

```
public class Result : IResult<string, Tokenizer>
{ /* implement interface */}

public class Tokenizer : ITokenizer<Result, string>
{ /* implement interface */}
```

Can anyone explain what's wrong? Maybe why it's impossible or how make this code correct?

P.S. For my task I can simply use `IResult<TValue, TToken>` interface without any constraints, but can I implement this without losing constraints?

Compiler errors:

```
(3:22) The type 'Test.IResult<TValue,TToken>' cannot be used as type parameter 'TResult' in the generic type or method 'Test.ITokenizer<TResult,TValue>'. 
There is no implicit reference conversion from 'Test.IResult<TValue,TToken>' to 
'Test.IResult<TValue,Test.ITokenizer<Test.IResult<TValue,TToken>,TValue>>'.
(10:22) The type 'Test.ITokenizer<TResult,TValue>' cannot be used as type parameter 'TToken' in the generic type or method 'Test.IResult<TValue,TToken>'. 
There is no implicit reference conversion from 'Test.ITokenizer<TResult,TValue>' to 
'Test.ITokenizer<Test.IResult<TValue,Test.ITokenizer<TResult,TValue>>,TValue>'.
```

Comment: 2 things: Please add the compile error to your post so we know what it is and secondly perhaps tell us what you are trying to do so we know why you chose this solution. There may be a better solution and you will get some more ideas.

Comment: @CodingYoshi I don't want to go deep into the situation because I want to understand  why this code doesn't compile. I think there is an underlying basic reason for it, that I don't understand now.

Comment: But you have circular reference there: IResult type constraints depend on ITokenizer and vica versa.

Comment: The error is clear and it is saying it cannot convert IResult<TValue, TToken> to IResult<TValue, ITokenizer<IResult<TValue, TToken>, TValue>>. I am not sure what else you want to know?

Comment: @Evk but why simple circular reference like `public interface Circular<T> where T : Circular<T>` is allowed and works?

Comment: @CodingYoshi but why it can't convert? I can simply deduce, that `IResult<TValue, TToken>` is `IResult<TValue, ITokenizer<IResult<TValue, TToken>, TValue>` from constraints

Comment: @NikitaSivukhin may be you should use [covariance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517) here?

Comment: @PavelVoronin yes, I think. But if I simply mark type parameters with `out` keyword there still compile errors... Or you suggest something different?

Comment: @NikitaSivukhin nope, nothing more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try to add one more type constraint to both interfaces, like this:

```
public interface IResult<TValue, TToken, TResult>
    where TToken : ITokenizer<TResult, TValue, TToken>
    where TResult : IResult<TValue, TToken, TResult> {
    TToken Tokenizer { get; }
    TValue Value { get; }
}

public interface ITokenizer<TResult, TValue, TTokenizer>
    where TResult : IResult<TValue, TTokenizer, TResult>
    where TTokenizer : ITokenizer<TResult, TValue, TTokenizer> {
    TResult Advance();
}
```

It is a bit more ugly, but I think will work for your goal:

```
public class Result : IResult<string, Tokenizer, Result>
{

}

public class Tokenizer : ITokenizer<Result, string, Tokenizer> {

}
```

I think the main problem is not circular references, but just the fact compiler cannot deduce implicit conversion between your generic types until you help it a bit.

UPDATE:
I think your interfaces lack strong relation between Tokenizer and Result. IResult interface says that TToken can be *any* tokenizer, I mean related to *any* Result. So it can be `ITokenizer<Result1>`, `ITokenizer<Result2>` and so on. But you cannot assign `ITokenizer<Result1>` to `ITokenizer<Result2>` (even though results implement the same interface) - that's different types. Same is true for tokenizer interface. When you change interface like above, it is now clear that `TToken` is tokenizer of `TResult`, and at the same time `TResult` is result of `TTokenizer` (now those are two concrete types, not interfaces, with strong relation between them).

Comment: @NikitaSivukhin see also my thoughts about the reasons (I think that it's not compiler cannot deduce, but those definitions are really wrong and should not compile).

Answer (score 0):

**Update**
Please disregard this answer since Evk's answer disproved this answer. However, I am still leaving this answer here because if someone else thinks it has to do with circular reference, it will help to explain that it clearly does not.

The issue is when the compiler is trying to compile the first interface, it needs to compile the second one but to compile the second one, it needs to compile the first one. Therefore, it cannot do so since it cannot arrive at a conclusion. To make things simpler, this code will get the same error as yours:

```
public interface IFirst<TFirst>
    where TFirst : ISecond<IFirst<TFirst>>
{

}

public interface ISecond<TSecond>
    where TSecond : IFirst<ISecond<TSecond>>
{ }
```

But the code below will not get errors since there is no circular reference and the compiler can arrive at a conclusion:

```
public interface IFirst<TFirst>
    where TFirst : ISecond<IFirst<TFirst>>
{

}

public interface ISecond<TSecond>
    //where TSecond : IFirst<ISecond<TSecond>>
{ }
```

Comment: Looks like @Evk disprove your argument for circular references :-)

Comment: he totally did. I am trying to wrap my head around it.